# Find critical points and perform second partials test

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y) = x(e^y -1)$$

I understand that I should now set fx = 0 and fy = 0, and I get the following:

$f_x = e^y - 1$

$f_y = e^y\cdot x$

From here however, I am unsure how to proceed and how to perform the second partials test. Would someone please advise? We are just learning this concept in our class. Thank you so much

Comment: Did you find the critical points first? Also, please write with LaTeX

Comment: sorry @Bcpicao yes the points were 0,0

Comment: No, the point $(0,0)$ is not a critical point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical points of $f(x,y)$ are where $\nabla f(x,y)=(f_x(x,y),f_y(x,y))$ is equal to zero. Solving for $x, y$ gives you the point $$(0,0)$$Now you are able to check the Hessian matrix (second derivative of a multivariate function) defined as $$H=\begin{bmatrix}{\partial^2f\over \partial x^2}&{\partial^2f\over \partial x\partial y}\\
{\partial^2f\over \partial x\partial y}&{\partial^2f\over \partial y^2}
\end{bmatrix}$$

and calculate it in $(0,0)$. $H(0,0)\succ0$ tells us that $(0,0)$ is a minimum and $H(0,0)\prec0$ tells us that $(0,0)$ is a maximum.

Comment: I was able to come up with the critical point being (0,0). Then I determined that since fxx(0,0) * fyy(0,0) - fxy(0,0)^2 = -1 (less than 0), that (0,0) is a saddle point. Does that mean it is also a maximum @mostafa Ayaz?

Comment: No, because it is a maximum over $y=-x$ and a minimum over $y=x$.